# What is the maximum number of messages getted from folder in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using @GET("/beta/me/mailFolders/{parentFolderId}/messages") for getting messages from folder in users mailbox, can I get 5000 messages in one request when setting parameter $top=5000?

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 1000, though that is not recommended.  The recommended approach is to do 100 and use paging.  The reason for this is that the more items you fetch in a single request, the longer that request takes and makes you more susceptible to timeouts and such.